# PHP: Download a file on button click?

Tags: php, download

I created a form, which, when a contained button is clicked, should open a download dialog to download a certain file. The file is placed on the same server.

I tried:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file . '"');
```

Where $file is a local path + the file name, for example c:\mypath\myfile.xls. This does not work though. It offers me a file, but its not a valid file. How else could I do that?

Note: I wrote c:\ because its still on my local machine for testing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
header("Pragma: public", true);
header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
die(file_get_contents($file));
```

I think file_get_contents() function is no longer work with PHP 5.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$path = "http://www.example.com/files/";
$filename = "abc.gif";

header("Content-Type:image/gif");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header("Cache-control: private");
header('X-Sendfile: '.$path);
readfile($path);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs in server side, you can not download the files in clients machine.

Upload the files to server and then give that path for download.

Comment: @user1856596 The server doesn't see it that way

Comment: Place the file where your php files are executing

Answer (score 0):

Path must be refered from the site root...move the file
ex:
script path : C:/wamp/www/test.php
file          C:/script.js
then:

```
if(file_exists('../../user.js'))
{
    echo "OK";
}
```

Still a bad ideea..