# Create a download button using html and php

Tags: php, html

I want to create a download button using HTML and PHP. Below is my HTML code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
       <form action="download.php" method="post">
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download File" />
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now I have created another file, called "download.php" and kept it in the same directory as my HTML file. Code of the PHP file is given below -

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/download');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Sample.mp3"');
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize("Sample.mp3"));
  $fp = fopen("Sample.mp3", "r");
  fpassthru($fp);
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

Sample.mp3 is kept in same folder as HTML file. I got these codes from internet.

Now my problem is, when I click on download button, content of the PHP file get opened rather than downloading the file.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Stupid questions perhaps but is PHP actually activated on the server?

Comment: `application/download` should be `audio/mpeg`

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: Did you read this one yet? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156711/php-download-a-file-on-button-click][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156711/php-download-a-file-on-button-click

Comment: Not sure whether PHP is activated or not. I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: its funny and suspicious that all answers -with code- got a -1

Comment: Since the browser is getting the content of the PHP file, any answer that just tweaks that content is nonsense. The problem is that the code isn't being executed, not that it is wrong.

Comment: I think PHP is not activated. I was just trying to create a button to download audio file. After searching over internet, I got the suggestion that I have to use PHP. I have never used PHP. So please bare with me. So, do I need to configure anything to use PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my problem is, when I click on download button, content of the PHP file get opened rather than downloading the file.

You need to run the script on:

- A webserver
- That supports PHP
- That is configured to treat that file as PHP

Answer (score 1):

You probably not run your .php file in a web server.

- Please install a personal web server to your computer like XAMPP or
  WAMP
- Then put your files into the www folder
- Open your browser
- Type localhost/your_HTML_file

Comment: Dont try man, just delete your answer so the theoretical guys take all the points

Comment: Why should this work when the original code did not? What did you change and why?

Comment: @vlzvl, Quentin is right. We should have read the question till the end.

Answer (score 1):

using PHP is more coding need ! If you are using html5 and only do this for download purpose ,you can use `<a>` link,that is easy and simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <a href="Sample.mp3" download>Download </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :)

```
<a href="/path/to/downloadfile.csv">
    <button class="btn">
        <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download
    </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this in php file:

```
$file = 'Sample.mp3'
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: Why should this work when the original code did not? What did you change and why?

Comment: @Quentin is right. We should have read the question till the end.